# Find div by multiple elements with Selenium WebDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

```
<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_1">Tee</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_1">Light Olive</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_2">Tee</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_2">Navy</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_3">Tee</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_3">Black</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_4">sweater</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_4">Light Olive</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_5">sweater</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_5">Navy</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_6">sweater</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_6">Black</a></p>
</div>
</article>
```

*if possible we have to rely on hypertext ('black', 'tee', sweater' and so on) because the website is dynamic and then they could remove tags like h1, p and so on. ty very much for the attention*

Suppose I want to click the div of the black sweater (note: **we are online on a dynamic website** and between the divs and around the divs we assume that there are indeterminate other divs so let's **forget that the div of the black sweater is the last one**).

1. We can't rely on URL addresses because they are dynamic.
2. We can't use

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text ('sweater'). click ()
```

because it would click the div of the Light Olive sweater.

3. We can't use

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text ('Black'). click ()
```

because it would click the first div of the black Tee.

As you can see the same article's divs are identical but the second link changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this XPATH:

```
//div[h1[.="sweater"]][p[.='Black']]
```

It is searching for div that has child nodes h1 and p with the text you want.

If you do not want to rely on particular tags, use the * symbol that means any element:

```
//div[*[.='sweater']][*[.='Black']]
```

Comment: it works perfectly, you won congrats really, but it has one flaw: as the site is dynamic and modifiable I would like to rely on the link text instead of the tags like h1 h2 h3 <p> and so on. can you adapt the response to this need? if so, I'll give you the crown victory

Comment: Done, have a look if this is what you meant.

Comment: trying to use `//div[a[text()='sweater']][a[text()='Black']]` but it doesnt work

Comment: the fact is that the only certainty we have is that there will be a hypertext while they could play assholes and remove any tags

Comment: So //div[*[.='sweater']][*[.='Black']] will not be stable enough? So need it with a?

Comment: your answer assumes that there is necessarily a tag when they could easily remove it, then yes i need it with "a"

Comment: What about //div[*/a[.='sweater']][*/a[.='Black']] ? Your XPath //div[a[text()='sweater']][a[text()='Black']] is not working as a is not direct child of the div

Comment: It could be also //div[*//a[.='sweater']][*//a[.='Black']] if you do not know have many nesting levels before the anchor you will have.

Comment: //div[//a[.='sweater']][//a[.='Black']] this will also work.

Comment: this last one doesn't work: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Comment: Does this work  //div[*//a[.='sweater']][*//a[.='Black']]?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `xpath` selectors in two steps(I'm using here lxml.html for example, but it should be easily converted to selenium webdriver `.find_element_by_xpath()`):

```
from lxml import html

s = """
<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_1">Tee</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_1">Light Olive</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_2">Tee</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_2">Navy</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_3">Tee</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_3">Black</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_4">sweater</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_4">Light Olive</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_5">sweater</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_5">Navy</a></p>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="inner-article">
<h1><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_6">sweater</a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="dinamic_URL_6">Black</a></p>
</div>
</article>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(s)

# step 1 filter out all divs including Black "items"
divs = [el.getparent().getparent() for el in tree.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Black')]")]

# step 2 filter our divs from step one to get the "sweater" item
needle = list(filter(lambda div: div.xpath("h1/a[contains(text(), 'sweater')]"), divs))[0]
```

Using selenium webdriver should be something like this(not tested, selenium not installed on my dev env):

```
# step 1 filter out all divs including Black "items"
divs = [el.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('..') for el in 
        web_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Black')]")]

# step 2 filter our divs from step one to get the "sweater" item
needle = list(filter(
    lambda div: div.find_element_by_xpath("h1/a[contains(text(), 'sweater')]"), divs))[0]
```

Comment: quite good, the problem is the webpage is online (in fact is dynamic)

Comment: What do you mean? You have two identifiers ("back" and "sweater") and the solution is filtering elements within "dynamic webpage" in two steps: by first identifier, then by second one.

Comment: what you said it's correct but i have to get black sweater div position *from a online website and not from a local string*, i can't upload all html source code in a string and so search in it. yes it would work but it's not the right way. if you can adjust your answer basing/relyig on a URL then you win

Comment: if you have to search an element on a webpage using selenium, i'm sure you will not upload the entire html source code in a string and then search inside it. you want directly identify it and probably your filters idee is on the right way

Comment: Updated the answer using selenium webdriver